# Go: Converting JSON string to map[string]interface{}

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to create a JSON representation within Go using a `map[string]interface{}` type. I'm dealing with JSON strings and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to avoid the JSON unmarshaler to automatically deal with numbers as float64s. As a result the following error occurs.

Ex.
`"{ 'a' : 9223372036854775807}"` should be `map[string]interface{} = [a 9223372036854775807` but in reality it is `map[string]interface{} = [a 9.2233720368547758088E18]`

I searched how structs can be used to avoid this by using `json.Number` but I'd really prefer using the `map` type designated above.

Comment: JSON defaults to using float64 for all numbers: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal.  If you want it to be an integer, you need to unmarshal it to a destination with an integer value (example, a `map[string]int` or a `struct{ a int }`).  That, or accept that it'll be a float and simply type-convert it to an int.

Comment: I'm aware that Go's `encoding/json` defaults to use float64s for json numbers. Type conversion would be the easiest solution if it worked with large int64 values. I guess I would have to write a custom marshaler or specify the map type. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [go `json.Unmarshal(...)` function](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) automatically uses float64 for JSON numbers. If you want to unmarshal numbers into a different type then you'll have to use a custom type with a custom unmarshaler. There is no way to force the unmarshaler to deserialize custom values into a generic map.

For example, here's how you could parse values of the "a" property as a [`big.Int`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int).

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "math/big"
)

type MyDoc struct {
  A BigA `json:"a"`
}

type BigA struct{ *big.Int }

func (a BigA) UnmarshalJSON(bs []byte) error {
  _, ok := a.SetString(string(bs), 10)
  if !ok {
    return fmt.Errorf("invalid integer %s", bs)
  }
  return nil
}

func main() {
  jsonstr := `{"a":9223372036854775807}`
  mydoc := MyDoc{A: BigA{new(big.Int)}}

  err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstr), &mydoc)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  fmt.Printf("OK: mydoc=%#v\n", mydoc)
  // OK: mydoc=main.MyDoc{A:9223372036854775807}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func jsonToMap(jsonStr string) map[string]interface{} {
    result := make(map[string]interface{})
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &result)
    return result
}
```

- Example - https://goplay.space/#ra7Gv8A5Heh
- Related questions - [create a JSON data as map[string]interface with the given data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58002614/create-a-json-data-as-mapstringinterface-with-the-given-data)